# Highchart - Displaying the last yaxis value in the guage

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is the guage chart i have, the way it displays - Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/11/

[image]

The range is from 0 to **550**, the tick interval is 100, **how do it get it to show the max value "550"?** as the last tick?. Although it does not fall into the interval of the tick interval. - http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/11/

Just the yaxis code here, so that it allows me to add the jsfiddle link - 
 yAxis: [{

```
                lineWidth: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 550,
                tickInterval: 100,
                tickPosition: 'outside',
                minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                tickLength: 15,
                minorTickLength: 0,
                labels: {
                    distance: 25,
                },
                offset: 5,
                endOnTick: false,
                title: {
                    y: -70
                },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, there are three options:

- allow Highcharts to handle last tick, by setting `yAxis.endOnTick = true`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/12/)
- if you have always the same extremes, set `yAxis.tickPositions`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/13/).
- if none of the above will suit you, then use `yAxis.tickPositioner` where you can write your own logic for ticks positions. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner).